# $f(x) :=\frac{f_1(x) + ... + f_n(x)}{n}$, $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, is the density of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-integrals

can someone of you say me if the following statement is true?

For $i = 1,...,n$ let $X_i$ be a real-valued random variable with density function $f_i$ on $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$.

Then the function $f(x) :=\frac{f_1(x) + ... + f_n(x)}{n}$, $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, is the density of a random variable.

For me the statement is true since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f_1(x) + ... + f_n(x)}{n}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f_1(x)}{n}+...+\frac{f_n(x)}{n}dx=n\frac1 n$=1

Comment: That's a good start to a proof.  What else do you need to show to conclude $f(x)$ is a density?

Comment: That the function is $\geq 0$ but this is obvious since all $f_n$ are positive

Comment: Just because something is obvious doesn't mean it's not important :)

Comment: You're right ;)